# Retrofit! Не могу найти метод setEndpoint()

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Нужен метод **setEndpoint()**, но его нет в библиотеке **Retroifit**. Метод **setEndpoint()** пытаюсь вызвать вот так:  `Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().`(здесь он должен быть). Может его переименовали?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), в `Retorfit2` используется метод `baseUrl()`.

Пример:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.github.com")
    .build();
```